# Median of a disjoint range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet of numbers by month and year, like so:

```
+-----+------+-------+
| Jul | 2018 | 123.0 |
+-----+------+-------+
| Jun | 2018 | 456.0 |
+-----+------+-------+
| May | 2018 | 789.0 |
+-----+------+-------+
```

The data goes back to 2004 or so. For each month, I want to find the median value over all years. Is there a good way to do this without re-ordering the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite Excel 2016 introducing `MAXIFS` and `MINIFS`, to go with `AVERAGEIFS`, there is still no `MEDIANIFS`,

However you can create this using an array formula:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(B:B="Feb",D:D,""))
```

"Feb" can be replaced with a cell value, so you can then drag down over a list.

Answer (score 4):

Use this array formula:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(A1:A200="Jan",C1:C200))
```

Confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode

Comment: I tip my hat to your superior Excel-fu.